# Optimizing a query with many subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I need to query data from two tables, one is a parent (batches) and the other a child (details), where I filter on the parent and want to return all items of the parent based on a where clause, but selectively filter different aspects of the child table into summary columns for the parent result set.

With that said, here is the query I have now that works: (sorry for the length, I stripped out some stuff that does not matter but wanted to keep the subqueries)

```
SELECT
  workid,
  siteid,
  (
    SELECT
      top 1 description
    FROM
      worksrcdesc a
    WHERE
      a.workid = b.workid
    AND
      a.site = b.site
    ORDER BY
      date DESC
  ) AS descript,
  itemid,
  mode,
  systemdate,
  (
    SELECT
      count(sequence)
    FROM
      details a
    WHERE
      a.reject = 0
    AND
      a.itemid = b.itemid
    AND
      a.siteid = b.siteid
    AND
      documenttype IN (1,2)
  ) AS documentcount,
  (
    SELECT
      count(sequence)
    FROM
      details a
    WHERE
      a.reject = 0
    AND
      a.itemid = b.itemid
    AND
      a.siteid = b.siteid
    AND
      documenttype = 15
  ) AS othercount,
  (
    SELECT
      count(distinct tranno)
    FROM
      details a
    WHERE
      a.reject = 0
    AND
      a.itemid = b.itemid
    AND
      a.siteid = b.siteid
  ) AS transactioncount,
  (
    SELECT
      top 1 groupnum
    FROM
      groups d
    WHERE
      b.siteid = d.siteid
    AND
      b.workid = d.workid
  ) AS sitegrouping
FROM
  batches b with (nolock)
WHERE
  workid IN (12345,67980)
ORDER BY
  workid ASC,
  itemid ASC
```

The batches table has 54,000 rows, which filtering by workid limits down to just 300 entries.  The details table has 3.3 million rows, which gets filtered down to around 76,000 rows based on the same criteria used on batches.

Right now this takes over 4-5 seconds to run on average; is there any way to simplify this to get it running faster? I thought about doing joins instead of subqueries, but what throws me off (and I cannot get it working) is the different where clauses on the subqueries.

Comment: You could use a Common Table Expression in place of each of those subqueries, and then select from the CTEs.

Comment: COrrelated subqueries like this tend to run row by row so you essentially have many cursors in your code.

Comment: Explain plan would help,correlated subqueries tend to be fast if all those WHERE columns are indexed.But we cant tell from the question alone if those indexes exist.

Comment: Sequence, siteid and itemid are all indexed as primary keys

Comment: I'm guessing that reject is a boolean (0 = false, 1 = true), so indexing on this field will likely not be highly selective.  Additionally, you stated that sequence, siteid, and item are all PRIMARY keys.  Pretty sure that is not the case either and only sequence is the primary and the other 2 are merely two _individual_ indexes.  If these assumptions are correct, consider adding a compound index with this column order (itemid, siteid, documenttype).

Comment: Post your schema so that people can be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

At least you could combine your subqueries into one outer apply:

```
outer apply (
    SELECT
      sum(case when documenttype IN (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) as documentcount,
      sum(case when documenttype = 15 then 1 else 0 end) as othercount,
      count(distinct tranno) as transactioncount
    FROM
      details a
    WHERE
      a.reject = 0 AND
      a.itemid = b.itemid AND
      a.siteid = b.siteid
   )
```

If sequence can be null, the you might need to check it in the sum clause too.

Also indexing is important, especially if the number of rows that match is high, so that time isn't spent on key lookups. Most likely you want to have index with itemid, siteid and reject + documenttype and tranno as included columns. This of course needs consideration if the table is updated heavily.

Comment: How does this apply to my select query? I'm not entirely understanding how this is used.

Comment: outer apply goes to the from part of the SQL, and you need to give this an alias, and then you can refer the columns with the alias, like this was a table

Comment: So I tried this, but it actually takes much longer to run compared to the subqueries (24-26 seconds, versus the 4-5 before). I aliased it as "dtl" and placed it after the parent table almost as another table, as you mentioned, then referenced the 3 columns using the dtl. prefix I created - it returns the correct data, just takes much longer to run.

Comment: I should also note, I do not have control on the structure or indexing of this table as it's for a vendor application. The only columns indexed are sequence, itemid and siteid

Comment: There's probably something happening with the query plan if it takes longer, checking the actual plan and statistics io output might help -- and might need more tweaking to get working better if the plan somehow gets worse